# Poisson distribution goes to normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and denote $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{\lambda}X$. By using mgf  I want to show that $\bar{X}$ goes to $N(1,\frac{1}{\lambda})$ as $\lambda$ increases.

More precisely, I want to show that, for $Y\sim N(1,\frac{1}{\lambda})$, $$|M_{\bar{X}}(t)-M_{Y}(t)|\leq \frac{C}{\lambda^2}$$

So we need to show that $$|e^{t+\frac{t^2}{2\lambda}}-e^{\lambda(e^{t/\lambda}-1)}| \leq \frac{C}{\lambda^2}.$$

I tried Taylor expansion but I couldn't simplify it.

Comment: What do you mean by "$\bar X$ goes to $N(1,\frac1\lambda)$ as $\lambda$ increases? If you take the limit as $\lambda\to\infty$ then the result will no longer be a function of $\lambda$.

Comment: I mean for large enough $\lambda$, poisson distribution is close enough to normal distribution.